# Visiting Clearnet websites using Tor Browser

Tags: browsers, clear-net

Does using the Tor Browser to visit Clearnet websites provide more privacy than visiting the same Clearnet websites using retail Firefox?

Comment: yes, that's one of the purposes of the Tor Browser.

Answer (score 1):

Generally yes, any requests to websites you visit in the Tor Browser whether it’s an onion address or a regular address will be routed through the Tor network. This means that any website you visit will not learn your IP address. Even with its new privacy features, Firefox does not hide your IP address.